# I want to customize Android at a source level and add code to automatically switch the default camera to the one connected by USB when it is available

Tags: android

I am trying to configure android such that instead of using the inbuilt camera, the applications use the external camera connected via a usb and otg. Can you please guide me if anyone knows the process for the query.
regards
Hardik Garg

Comment: Do you have access to the source-code. If yes, is the source-code public. If yes, can you add the URL to have a look at it? Please edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Hey @MadMike, I am new to this part, so can you please explain more regarding what are you asking for?

Comment: Please read [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first problem with your question is: you don't seem to have done *any* research. Do your research. Show the results. **Don't** show it as a comment here. **Edit** your question and add it there.